# マクロの二段階展開について教えてください。

Tags: c

プリプロセッサに詳しい方にお聞きしたいのですが[、ここの](https://www.jpcert.or.jp/sc-rules/c-pre05-c.html)
このコードがどういう順番で展開されるために、NGなのか

```
#define str(s) #s　　　①
#define foo 4　　　　　　②

str(foo);
```

下ではなぜOKなのか

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
#define foo 4
```

私には理解できませんでした。

```
#define JOIN(x, y) JOIN_AGAIN(x, y)
#define JOIN_AGAIN(x, y) x ## y
```

上ののコードもわかりませんでした。

Comment: リンクも貼ったし、どっちでもいいかなって思った。けど、週末までには書き直す。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JISの文章を引用すると

> 実引数の中のすべてのマクロを展開する。ただし、置換内容列の中の次の仮引数は除く
>   - 前処理字句 # または ## が前にある仮引数
>   - 前処理字句 ## が後に続く仮引数
>   JIS X 3014:2003 (ISO/IEC 14882:2003) 16.3.1 実引数代入
>   JIS X 3010:2003 (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) 6.10.3.1 実引数置換

端的に説明すると、引数の先が#だったり##だったら置換しません。ということ
なので

```
#define str(s) #s　　　①
#define foo 4　　　　　　②
```

こう書いてしまうと

```
str(foo);
```

引数の先が#なので②は置換されずに`"foo"`と扱われてしまう。そこで、以下のように書く

```
#define str(s) str_cp(s) 
#define str_cp(s) #s　　　◎
#define foo 4　　　　　　
str(foo);
```

すると無意味に感じられる◎は一度目の置換動作で

```
#define str_cp(s) #s　　　◎
str_cp(4);
```

となり、最終的に`"4"`と望む結果が得られる。
実行順序を考えると#や##が先で定数やマクロ関数が次という考え方もできる。

Answer (score 5):

JIS X 3014:2003 (ISO/IEC 14882:2003) 16.3.1 実引数代入
JIS X 3010:2003 (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) 6.10.3.1 実引数置換

> 実引数の中のすべてのマクロを展開する。ただし、置換内容列の中の次の仮引数は除く
>   - 前処理字句 `#` または `##` が前にある仮引数
>   - 前処理字句 `##` が後に続く仮引数

これがどういう意味か、というと

`#` あるいは `##` の対象は、そのマクロの仮引数に与えられた字句（ソースコードに記述した文字の列）そのものです。この質問での提示例 `str(foo)` の引数は `foo` という字句ですが、 `foo` が `#define` されてても置換しない、あくまで `foo` という字句であるものとして扱う、ということです。

提示 `str` は字句を文字列化するマクロなので、結果は `"foo"` となります。 `"4"` とはなりません。

さて `__FILE__` と `__LINE__` は `#define` されているかのごとくに振舞う仕様です。

```
#define __FILE__ "example.c"
#define __LINE__ 17
```

リンク先の `static_assert` の最終展開結果が `assertion_failed_at_line___LINE__` ではおいしくなくて `assertion_failed_at_line_17` であってほしいわけです。であれば `#`  や `##` の直接対象に `__LINE__` という字句ではなくて、その展開結果 `17` を与えたいわけです。そのためにはもう一段マクロをかませて、１段目には `#` や `##` を使わないことでマクロ展開を行わせ、２段目はその展開結果に `#` や `##` を適用し結合させる、ことで目的を達成できることになります。

Comment: 要するに①しか適応されてない。じゃ、なんで②は適応されなかったの←こういった子供っぽい質問です。多分聞きたいのは優先順位の問題です。もし仮に①②が逆になったとしても？ですか

Comment: ③ str(foo) に対して②が適用されない根拠を示したつもりですがどこがわかりませんか？　ソースコード上①と②が逆順に現れても同じことです。